# How does maxRequestsPerConnection of istio work?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

everyone.

I have been learning istio and to understand how maxRequestsPerConnection works, I applied the manifest below.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  host: httpbin
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      http:
        maxRequestsPerConnection: 1
```

`httpbin` is a sample service of istio.

I thought `maxRequestsPerConnection` means how many http requests are allowed per one TCP Connection, and istio would close tcp connection after pod received one http request in this case.

After applying, I sent some http requests using telnet. I thought istio would accept the request once and then close the TCP connection, but istio didn't.

```
$ telnet httpbin 8000
Trying 10.76.12.133...
Connected to httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /get HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Telnet [ja] (Linux)
Host: httpbin

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: envoy
date: Sun, 07 Nov 2021 14:14:16 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 579
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 9

{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Host": "httpbin", 
    "User-Agent": "Telnet [ja] (Linux)", 
    "X-B3-Parentspanid": "b042ad708e2a47a2", 
    "X-B3-Sampled": "1", 
    "X-B3-Spanid": "b6a08d45e1a1e15e", 
    "X-B3-Traceid": "fc23863eafb0322db042ad708e2a47a2", 
    "X-Envoy-Attempt-Count": "1", 
    "X-Forwarded-Client-Cert": "By=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/default/sa/httpbin;Hash=d9bb27f31fe44200f803dbe736419b4664b5b81045bb3811711119ca5ccf6a37;Subject=\"\";URI=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/default/sa/default"
  }, 
  "origin": "127.0.0.6", 
  "url": "http://httpbin/get"
}
GET /get HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Telnet [ja] (Linux)
Host: httpbin

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: envoy
date: Sun, 07 Nov 2021 14:14:18 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 579
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 3

{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Host": "httpbin", 
    "User-Agent": "Telnet [ja] (Linux)", 
    "X-B3-Parentspanid": "85722c0d777e8537", 
    "X-B3-Sampled": "1", 
    "X-B3-Spanid": "31d2acc5348a6fc5", 
    "X-B3-Traceid": "d7ada94a092d681885722c0d777e8537", 
    "X-Envoy-Attempt-Count": "1", 
    "X-Forwarded-Client-Cert": "By=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/default/sa/httpbin;Hash=d9bb27f31fe44200f803dbe736419b4664b5b81045bb3811711119ca5ccf6a37;Subject=\"\";URI=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/default/sa/default"
  }, 
  "origin": "127.0.0.6", 
  "url": "http://httpbin/get"
}
```

After this, I sent http request ten times using fortio, and I got the same result.

```
$ kubectl exec "$FORTIO_POD" -c fortio -- /usr/bin/fortio load -c 1 -qps 0 -n 10 -loglevel Warning http://httpbin:8000/get
14:22:56 I logger.go:127> Log level is now 3 Warning (was 2 Info)
Fortio 1.17.1 running at 0 queries per second, 2->2 procs, for 10 calls: http://httpbin:8000/get
Starting at max qps with 1 thread(s) [gomax 2] for exactly 10 calls (10 per thread + 0)
Ended after 106.50891ms : 10 calls. qps=93.889
Aggregated Function Time : count 10 avg 0.010648204 +/- 0.01639 min 0.003757335 max 0.059256801 sum 0.106482036
# range, mid point, percentile, count
>= 0.00375734 <= 0.004 , 0.00387867 , 30.00, 3
> 0.004 <= 0.005 , 0.0045 , 70.00, 4
> 0.005 <= 0.006 , 0.0055 , 80.00, 1
> 0.012 <= 0.014 , 0.013 , 90.00, 1
> 0.05 <= 0.0592568 , 0.0546284 , 100.00, 1
# target 50% 0.0045
# target 75% 0.0055
# target 90% 0.014
# target 99% 0.0583311
# target 99.9% 0.0591642
Sockets used: 1 (for perfect keepalive, would be 1)
Jitter: false
Code 200 : 10 (100.0 %)
Response Header Sizes : count 10 avg 230.1 +/- 0.3 min 230 max 231 sum 2301
Response Body/Total Sizes : count 10 avg 824.1 +/- 0.3 min 824 max 825 sum 8241
All done 10 calls (plus 0 warmup) 10.648 ms avg, 93.9 qps
$
```

In my understanding, the message `Sockets used: 1 (for perfect keepalive, would be 1)` means fortio used only one TCP connection.

I guessed clients used different tcp connection for each http requests first, but if it is true, telnet connection was not closed by foreign host and fortio used ten tcp connections.

Please teach me what the function of `maxRequestsPerConnection` is.

Comment: I recently posted an answer for a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69822560/15659347). Does this answer your question?

Comment: I'm afraid but it does not work for me.
My question is what is the function of `maxRequestsPerConnection`, but your answer says setting maxRequestsPerConnection to 1 disables Keep-Alive.
I know this function due to istio document, but my result of verification does not follow this document and your answer. So that, I want to know why, and what the function of maxRequestsPerConnection is.

Comment: By the way, as you may know, I was the one who asked that question.

Comment: Oh, wow, I don't know how I missed that. How did you provision your cluster? Is Istio installed with `istioctl` or with operator (or possibly any other way)? Which version of Istio and Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: You help me many time, I really appreciate it. My cluster is GKE and kubernetes version is 1.21.5. I installed istio using `istioctl` and its version is 1.11.4.

Comment: If you know the correct operation and can reproduce it, could you please tell me how?